Can't generate a RealmModel that has a RealmModel parameter
import 'package:realm/realm.dart';

part 'command.realm.dart';

@RealmModel()
class _Command {
  @PrimaryKey()
  late ObjectId id;
  late String command;
  late String status;
  late DateTime tagab;
}


Hello, I am trying to have a class named UserDatabase that will have a parameter "List commands". Where the Command class is provided above. After running:
dart run realm generate
The Command class was generated successfully.
Now I am trying to create the UserDatabase class like this:
import 'package:realm/realm.dart';
import 'command.dart';
part 'user_database.realm.dart';

@RealmModel()
class _UserDatabase {
  @PrimaryKey()
  late ObjectId id;

  late String user_id;
  late List<Command> commands;
}


And when running dart run realm generate, I get this output:
5   │ @RealmModel()
6   │ class _UserDatabase {
    │       ━━━━━━━━━━━━━ in realm model for 'UserDatabase'
... │
11  │   late List<Command> commands;
    │        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ List<InvalidType> is not a realm model type

Where am I wrong? Thank you.

How about late List<_Command> command;

Same issue. "Not a realm type
in: package:boom/realm/user_database.dart:12:8
╷
5   │ @RealmModel()
6   │ class _UserDatabase {
│       ━━━━━━━━━━━━━ in realm model for 'UserDatabase'
... │
12  │   late List<_Command> commands;
│        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ List is not a realm model type"

Oh. import 'package:realm_dart/realm.dart';?

The problem occurs because Realm's code generator doesn't recognize Command as a valid type for a List property in another RealmModel.
Realm in Dart does not allow a List of objects that are not Realm models themselves
We can fix it by  using RealmList<_Command to ensure that list type is compatible with Realm's data model
import 'package:realm/realm.dart';
import 'command.dart';

part 'user_database.realm.dart';

@RealmModel()
class _UserDatabase {
  @PrimaryKey()
  late ObjectId id;

  late String user_id;
  late RealmList<_Command> commands;
}

With this setup, running dart run realm generate should successfully generate the UserDatabase model without any errors.
Tip: Always use Realm-specific types like RealmList for collections and relationships between models. This applies to all complex types in your models.

Unfortunately it doesn't work. This is the output now: 14  │ @RealmModel()
15  │ class _UserDatabase {
│       ━━━━━━━━━━━━━ in realm model for 'UserDatabase'
... │
20  │   late RealmList commands;
│        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ RealmList is not a realm model type
╵
┌──> package:realm_dart/src/list.dart
24  │ abstract class RealmList<T extends Object?> with RealmEntity implements List {
│                ━━━━━━━━━
╵
"Add a RealmModel annotation on 'RealmList', or an Ignored annotation on 'commands'."
